# How to submit a form using JQuery depending on which option a user chooses

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've looked around at a few different questions with regards to this topic and no breakthroughts. What I'm trying to do is when the user clicks on the `submit` button I show 3 buttons on the screen and if the user clicks the third button the form submits. Otherwise I prevent the form from submitting.

However I'm having trouble implementing this. Currently I'm doing it this way and from my research i saw the very obvious mistake I was making with calling `e.preventDefault()` as soon as the form is submitted which prevents it from being able to be submit.

Hopefully in my code you will see what I'm trying to do. Show the three options before the form is submit and only submit if the third option is selected.

HTML:

```
<form action="some_url" method="post">
    <input type="text" value="" id="fname" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<br/>
<div id="option-box"> 
 <span id="option-a">Option A</span>
 <span id="option-b">Option B</span>
 <span id="option-c">Option C</span>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```js
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#option-box').show();

    $('#option-a').click(function () {
        alert('option a');
        //Do something else
    });
    $('#option-b').click(function () {
        alert('option b');
        //Do something else
    });
    $('#option-c').click(function () {
        alert('option c - SUBMIT');
        $('form').submit();
    });

});
```

```css
#option-box {
    display: none;
}
#option-box span {
    background:green;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding:5px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    text-align:center;
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="some_url" method="post">
    <input type="text" value="" id="fname" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<br/>
<div id="option-box"> 
 <span id="option-a">Option A</span>
 <span id="option-b">Option B</span>
 <span id="option-c">Option C</span>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle of my current code:

https://jsfiddle.net/javacadabra/rb553ttw/1/

Comment: Why are they not actual buttons? Since they are not buttons, you should not have to do anything to prevent a form submission.

Comment: Because I mocked somethign up in JSFiddle very quickly

Comment: Did you try searching google? There is boatloads of info on this online :/

Comment: I wouldn't have asked it I didn't search google.... Thanks for helpful advice though.

Comment: Changed answer to support simple state checking (also works well with checkboxes). Toggling events `on` and `off` can be a real maintenance/debugging problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent submitting the form to start

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //<-- Need this
    //... other code
});
```

Adding event handlers inside another action can also lead to issues. Submit more than once, you will have more event handlers attached. So you need to remove previous events. You can remove them with [`off`](https://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
 $('#option-a').off("click").on("click", function () { /* other code */ });
```

Lastly you should not need to cancel the default action of the *buttons* since they should not do anything.

And if you want to submit the form, you probably want to unbind the submit method or call it from DOM directly.

```
$('form').off("submit").submit();
```

or

```
$('form')[0].submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Take note of what the last selection was, and `preventDefault` based on that selection:

```
var selectedOption = "";

$('form').submit(function (e) {
    $('#option-box').show();
    if (selectedOption != "option-c") {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

$('#option-box').on('click', 'span', function () {
    selectedOption = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/rb553ttw/4/

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways I can think of for the solution.

### 1. Remove type="submit"

Here instead of making `<button type="submit">` you can make it `<button type="button">` which does not submit the form unless you specify it in your script on click event listener `$('form').submit()`

### 2. Activate button on choosing option

Here your submit button is initially disabled. You can call the function using `onClick` event on the option or in the script and remove the disabled property of the button

### 3. Apply form action url on choosing option

Similar to 2nd option, here you will set the action url when the user selects a particular option using the script. In case user selects any other option and clicks on submit, no action will be performed